# MySQL multiple selects in one query retrieve nested array

Tags: php, mysql

**[UPDATED]**

I'm trying to select data from one table but try to get them in different order

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY timestamp DESC
) mostrecent

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM
( 
  SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY timestamp ASC
) oldest
```

now this will retrieve records in a different order. the newest videos and oldest videos...

```
foreach($table as $key=>$value)
{
$row_tmb[$key] = $value;
}
$array[] = $row_tmb;
```

---

when printing data

```
print_r($array);
```

I get

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [vid] => 1 [title] => title1 [timestamp] => newer) 
        [1] => Array ( [vid] => 2 [title] => title2 [timestamp] => older
        //from second select...
        [2] => Array ( [vid] => 2 [title] => title2 [timestamp] => older
        [3] => Array ( [vid] => 1 [title] => title1 [timestamp] => newer
)
```

I want

```
Array('newest' => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [vid] => 1 [title] => title1 [timestamp] => newer) 
        [1] => Array ( [vid] => 2 [title] => title2 [timestamp] => older))
        //from second select...
Array('oldest' => Array (
        [0] => Array ( [vid] => 2 [title] => title2 [timestamp] => older
        [1] => Array ( [vid] => 1 [title] => title1 [timestamp] => newer))
```

Comment: your question is not clear..please explain clearly

Comment: i hope this will help make it clear

Comment: So you don't have a LIMIT clause anywhere?

Comment: i might need to limit foreach select too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) clearly states: *the use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.*

I suggest you use a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM videos
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

get the data in a PHP array then use PHP code to duplicate it and combine it as you need. This is some sample code that uses `mysqli`. Using `PDO` is similar:

```
// You should add a LIMIT to the query or it will take a lot of time and consume
// a lot of memory when the table gets bigger (several thousand rows)
$query  = 'SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY timestamp DESC';
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

// Retrieve the data
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

// Use the retrieved data to get the combined result
$array = array(
    'newest' => $data,
    'oldest' => array_reverse($data),
);
```

**Update:**

Assuming the column `timestamp` contains an integer value (a timestamp), you can achieve the same result from `MySQL` with a query like this:

```
(
    SELECT *, 'newest' AS source, timestamp AS sortColumn
    FROM videos
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT *, 'oldest' AS source, -timestamp AS sortColumn
    FROM videos
)
ORDER BY sortColumn DESC
```

If the `timestamp` column is not an integer value but a `DATE` then use `FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) AS sortColumn` instead. The idea is to compute a value that can be used for the final sorting (at the `UNION` level) and store it in the new column `sortColumn`.

The `source` column is used in the PHP to know the group each record belongs to (newest vs. oldest records).

```
// The lists of data split by source
$array = array(
    'newest' => array(),
    'oldest' => array(),
);
// Retrieve the data, put it into the correct list
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[$row['source']] = $row;
}
```

**Remark:** for medium and large tables (thousands of rows and more) it will run slow because it cannot use an index. For tables of this size doesn't make much sense to select all the records anyway. You will probably write something like this:

```
(
    SELECT *, 'newest' AS source, timestamp AS sortColumn
    FROM videos
    ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    LIMIT 100
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT *, 'oldest' AS source, nbVotes AS sortColumn
    FROM videos
    ORDER BY timestamp ASC
    LIMIT 100
)
ORDER BY sortColumn DESC
```

to select the most recent 100 rows and the oldest 100 rows. The final result starts with the newest records sorted by `timestamp` descending (newest first) then come the oldest records sorted by the number of votes (column `nbVotes`) they received, descending (I assumed no video has more than 1.3 billion votes).

Comment: @MustafaMJalal: then what do you actually need? How can we possibly answer your question if you won't explain your actual problem?

Comment: As explained in the documentation, `UNION` does not preserve the order of the rows produced by the `SELECT`s it combines and it does not guarantee that the rows produced by the first `SELECT` come before those produced by the second `SELECT`. Using `ORDER BY` on the `SELECT` queries is useful when it is combined with `LIMIT`. In order to achieve sorting on the `UNION`ed result set you have to enclose the `SELECT`s into parenthesis and add an `ORDER BY` clause a the `UNION` level. To keep the order of the rows you can `SELECT` an extra computed column containing a properly crafted expression.

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution that uses only `SQL` to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an outer query in the select statement like this:

```
select
    *
from
    (
        SELECT
            'Newest',col1,col2,etc
        FROM
            (
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                videos 
            ORDER BY 
                timestamp DESC
            )mostrecent
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            'Oldest',col1,col2,etc
        FROM
            (
            SELECT 
                * 
            FROM 
                videos 
            ORDER BY 
                timestamp DESC
            )oldest
    ) someTable
order by
    1 asc
```

This will then order the results first by the Newest/Oldest and then as you had it.

This won't give you two arrays like you show your desired output, but it will pretty much give you the same thing you want except in one array. You could however simply check the first column in your PHP code and then put it into the right array to get your desired nested array.

Edit: Added alias to derived table. Not to be picky, but in the same time you wrote "Doesn't even work" you could have picked up the omission and had a working query. C'mon mate, answers are here to help, not always to do your work for you :)

Comment: @MustafaMJalal: yes it does. There's nothing wrong with the given query.

Comment: it says 
Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @MustafaMJalal: looks like it's been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this would be an ideal answer, but at least I didn't have to mysql query two times.
because I know that I only need two records from each selection.

```
$newest = array($videos[0], $videos[1]);
$oldest = array($videos[2], $videos[3]);
```

now this even makes it easier to work with when retrieve to html...